# I am having trouble converting my nested json into a dataframe. I am getting the json from an API and want it in a dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, api, dataframe

This code is from Sportradar API. The API outputs the data as JSON or XML; below is my attempt at taking the JSON and making it into a dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import http.client
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

#API Call including my key
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.sportradar.us")

conn.request("GET", "/nfl/official/trial/v5/en/players/0acdcd3b-5442-4311-a139-ae7c506faf88/profile.json?api_key=99s3ewmn5rrdrd9r3v5wrfgd")
#conn.request("GET", "/nfl/official/trial/v5/en/games/b7aeb58f-7987-4202-bc41-3ad9a5b83fa4/pbp.json?api_key=99s3ewmn5rrdrd9r3v5wrfgd")
#conn.request("GET", "/nfl/official/trial/v5/en/teams/0d855753-ea21-4953-89f9-0e20aff9eb73/full_roster.json?api_key=99s3ewmn5rrdrd9r3v5wrfgd")
#conn.request("GET", "/nfl/official/trial/v5/en/games/030d37cf-b896-4f10-b16e-2a5120fef6cf/pbp.json?api_key=99s3ewmn5rrdrd9r3v5wrfgd")
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
data_dec = data.decode("utf-8")

json_data = json.loads(data_dec)
flat_data = json_normalize(json_data)

print(json_data)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(flat_data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_data, orient='index')
df2.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

#The closest thing to a dataframe I can get
df.head()
```

Comment: What is the specific issue you have? How does the result from your current code differ from what you want/expect? Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of a Python Wrapper that is publicly available and maintained.
See [link](https://github.com/johnwmillr/SportradarAPIs).

Comment: You--my friend--are brilliant. Thank you!